# Android - How to get the index of listItems from the list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am trying to get index of the list item, through which i can set different views for different items in another activity. Here is my code..

```
String description[] = {"inspiron","pavilion","macbook"}; /* i want this list on another activity after clicking listitem of first activity.*/

ArrayList<String> listDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
String ArrayDesc[] = null;

ListView listViewDesc;

ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapterDesc;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.category);

            for(int i = 0;i<description.length;i++)
    {
        listDesc.add(description[i]);
    }

    ArrayDesc = (String[]) listDesc.toArray();

       listAdapterDesc=newrrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ArrayDesc);
   listViewDesc.setAdapter(listAdapterDesc);
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
   {

      lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                 @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v, int i, long l)
                    {

                     /*here i want some code to extract list item index from list to set 
                     different lists according to the item click on another view.*/


                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), categorySelected.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });
```

Comment: `String item =(String)a.getItemAtPosition(i);` in on item click. I you need just the index use `i`.

Comment: Since you just want the position, just use `i` in onItemClick. it is the position in the adapter of the item that was clicked.

Comment: "i want this list on another activity after clicking listitem of first activity". you want the item or the index?

Comment: @Raghunandan How can i show you my full code? because there is a code limit here and problem is the previous part of my code which was executing correctly now giving no output to the emmulator after adding this code which you just told.

Comment: @user2113484 what is the problem? No need to show the full code . I guess you have posted the relevant part. But did you use `intent.putExtra("key",item);` and retrieve the string item in the categorySelected class?

Comment: @user2113484 if you need just index no need of the code i posted. just use `int i` param of `onItemClick`

Comment: no for now i just testing that it is giving the write index,just made a Toast to check desired output

Comment: please show me the code if any item from the list is clicked its index number will pop-up (in Toast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments You say

please show me the code if any item from the list is clicked its index number will pop-up (in Toast)

So Try the below

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v, int i, long l)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Index of the item clicked is"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), categorySelected.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: ok cool. now i am setting if/else like if(i == 0){ /* here i want to set name and age for another activity but name and age both have there own linear layout*/ }

Comment: @user2113484 that's a different part. i guess i have answered your current question

Comment: @user2113484 does it work? if it helps mark the answer as accepted and a different question start a new thread by posting your if else code there